# How to turn the Red Light (infrared or optical sound output light) off?

Tags: sound, spdif

There is a red light turned on (it seems an infrared light or optical sound) when I boot Ubuntu, and it remains always on, but not when I boot MacOS in a MacBook Pro.
How can I save energy with Ubuntu as much as with MacOS and have it turned off?
Also, bluetooth should always be turned off at boot time, unless you configure it to be on.

Comment: Could you possibly add a picture of that?

Comment: no. But it is on the left side of a macbook pro 3,1 and the icon is a headphone set

Comment: If you can see the red light, I think it cannot be called as infrared. The TV remotes have infrared LEDs and you can't see the light when they are on (unless accompanied by other LEDs in the visible spectrum).

Comment: Sorry, I wrote it could be an optical sound something but the comment didn't went out because tags were missing and when I send it again that was lost somehow. Sometimes the tvs turn a red light on when receive the infrared.

Comment: That red light is a feedback/acknowledgement to show that the tv has recieved your command from the remote.

Comment: It doesn't matter. Obviously, I would like to know why ubuntu has that light always on? If there is an unnecessary process going on, and how to turn off all what is not needed.

Comment: Probably the S/PDIF (digital/optical) output of your sound card. I have such an LED glowing at my PC's rear, but never bothered to check if I can turn it off

Comment: Yes, it is the s/PDIF. You can turn it off, and the light turns off if you run alsamixer, move to s/pdif and type "M". But it will take hours and hours of horrible investigation to see how and if I can turn it off at boot time without having problems in the future when I forget what I touched, hahaha. Always the same story!

Comment: Turned mine off too ;o)

Comment: Unless the Bluetooth issue is related, you may want to post another (separate) question about that. But if you think you've identified something wrong with Ubuntu that should be fixed, then you should [report a bug](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ReportingBugs) instead. Anyways, I hope you get an answer to your main question about the red light soon!

Answer (score 5):

Mute the "S/PDIF" control in `alsamixer` and then run `sudo alsactl store` to make this persist across reboots.